# Почему не открывает JSP страницу(Servlet JAVA)

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Main JSP page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h3>Welcome</h3> <hr/> ${user}, hello! <hr/>
     <a href="controller?command=logout">Logout</a>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Код для ее возвращения:

```
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(page);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <description>MySQL</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>MySQL DB Connection Pool</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/airline</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/controller</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Лог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за %20 в url?

Comment: @Tachkin, где в окне браузера "%20"? Отправить запрос на страницу - написать url JSP страницы и посмотреть откроет ли ее браузер?

Comment: @bsuart, а не сработает так? Жаль, я думал, что можно просто прописать адрес jsp, что бы протестировать генерацию.

Comment: посмотрите в лог сервера. есть там ошибки? в web.xml сервлет как описан?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, в логах ничего не показывает, представил web.xml

Comment: скорей всего у вас в переменной **page** что-то не то записано. попробуйте вывести ее содержимое в лог.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, пробовал,добавил в вопрос, содержимое переменой - правильный путь к странице. Причем error.jsp отображается, а main.jsp - нет.

Comment: @Tachkin, нет так не сработает. JSP - это не html. Просто так "прописать адрес jsp" не протестировать jsp страницу.

Comment: @studentST, проблема здесь однозначно в содержимом page. Проверьте её содержимое

Comment: при выводе в лог добавьте к содержимому переменной в начале и в конце какой-нибудь символ, например `*`. что бы было видно, что в начале и в конце нет пробелов и пр. невидимых символов.